# sklearn.neighbors.KDTree memory requirements

Tags: scikit-learn, kdtree

In the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html) for *sklearn.neighbors.KDTree* there is a description of memory consumption:

> The amount of memory needed to store the tree scales as approximately n_samples / leaf_size.

Does this mean that when *leaf_size* gets bigger, the memory needed to store a tree decreases?

I thought *leaf_size* specifies how many leaf nodes there are in the tree, so if there are many nodes, the memory grows. Am I thinking about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 4):

The `leaf_size` parameter specifies how many entries are stored in the terminal 'leaves' at the bottom of the 'branches' of the tree. Another way of saying this is it is the number of 'neighbors' that your query will be compared to exhaustively...

If you have a smaller `leaf_size`. The tree needs to be bigger, hence it increases the memory requirements to store the tree.

In practice, the `leaf_size` can drastically affect computation time and is a balance between the cost of accessing a larger tree for each query (small `leaf_size`), and the cost of exhaustive comparison of more objects for each query (larger `leaf_size`)

For more detail see the optimisation of leaf_size here:
https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/04/29/benchmarking-nearest-neighbor-searches-in-python/